# Error in map Fragment with tabular Form

Tags: android, android-fragments, dictionary, fragment

i am using map fragment in tab view , in first and second tab i am displaying list view but in last tab using map fragment .When i am clicking on last tab for  first time it is displaying correct map view but during second time app crashes.Please let me know how to handle  .
Error is

```
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #118: Error inflating class fragment
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at competent.groove.thegroove.partypartner.Party_Partner_Confirm_Fragment.onCreateView(Party_Partner_Confirm_Fragment.java:62)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1291)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #118: Duplicate id 0x7f060208, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4248)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
11-12 17:53:26.794: E/AndroidRuntime(10174):    ... 20 more
```

And Layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" > 

        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" >
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you inflating, map inside a fragment or inside an Activity?

Comment: In fragment, In  OncreateView i have done

         if (googleMap == null) {
             googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                     R.id.map)).getMap();
  
             // check if map is created successfully or not
             if (googleMap == null) {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                         "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                         .show();
             }
         }

Comment: remove Fragment from `FragmentTrasation` in `onDestroyView()` in your Fragment....

Comment: Inside a Fragment you can not add Fragment.

Comment: actually when u come to first tab second time, it call that tab again.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, in your xml file just add one LinearLayout instead of Map Fragment like below:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="Wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >
```

Then in your Fragment:

```
private LinearLayout lnrMap;
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private Timer t = null;

    lnrMap = (LinearLayout)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.lnrMap);
    mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    addFragment(lnrMap.getId(), mapFragment);
    t = new Timer();
                t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {

                                    googleMap = mapFragment.getExtendedMap();

                                    mapFragment.getView().setClickable(false);
                                    if (googleMap != null) {
                                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
                                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
                                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
                                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
                                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
                                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(6));

                                        t.cancel();
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                }

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }, 0, 500);


//addFragment() method:

public void addFragment(int layoutId, Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(layoutId, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```